# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Sitedeteste\upload.php on line 37

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Sitedeteste\upload.php on line 37
```

```
<?php

//Funcao que vai abrir o arquivo php que faz conexao com o servidor

require_once ("sistemadelogin.php");
$descricao = $_POST[descimagem];

$nomeFOTOG = $_FILES['fotoimagem']['name'];
$nomeFOTOP = $_FILES['miniImagem']['name'];

$tmpFOTOG = $_FILES['fotoimagem']['tmp_name'];
$tmpFOTOP = $_FILES['miniImagem']['tmp_name'];

$destinoG = "fotoG/" .$nomeFOTOG;
$destinoP = "fotoP/" .$nomeFOTOP;

if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFOTOG, $destinoG)){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFOTOP, $destinoP)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbimagens (descimagem, fotoimagem, miniImagem) VALUES ('$descricao', '$destinoG', '$destinoP')";
        if($query = @mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na Insercao no Banco de Dados".mysql_error())){

        header("Location: index.php");  

        }else{

            echo "Ocorreu uma Falha no Cadastro da Imagem";     

            }


        }else {

        echo "Erro ao fazer UPLOAD da Foto Grande";

        }

?>
```

Comment: Indent your code properly and all would be clear. You're missing a closing `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wooble is correct, you are missing a closing bracket on one of your if statements. The following code should do the trick

```
<?php

//Funcao que vai abrir o arquivo php que faz conexao com o servidor

require_once ("sistemadelogin.php");
$descricao = $_POST[descimagem];

$nomeFOTOG = $_FILES['fotoimagem']['name'];
$nomeFOTOP = $_FILES['miniImagem']['name'];

$tmpFOTOG = $_FILES['fotoimagem']['tmp_name'];
$tmpFOTOP = $_FILES['miniImagem']['tmp_name'];

$destinoG = "fotoG/" .$nomeFOTOG;
$destinoP = "fotoP/" .$nomeFOTOP;

if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFOTOG, $destinoG)){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFOTOP, $destinoP)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbimagens (descimagem, fotoimagem, miniImagem) VALUES ('$descricao', '$destinoG', '$destinoP')";
        if($query = @mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na Insercao no Banco de Dados".mysql_error())){

            header("Location: index.php");  

        }else{

            echo "Ocorreu uma Falha no Cadastro da Imagem";     

        }


    }else {

        echo "Erro ao fazer UPLOAD da Foto Grande";

    }

}

?>
```